# roundcubelogin with window.open function

Tags: drupal-7, roundcube

I have already done autologin to roundcube via the following script

```
<form name="webmail" action="http://localhost/roundcube_mail/" method="post">
    <div class="info" style="color:#f00;display:none"></div>

    <input name="_action" id="_action"value="login" type="hidden" />
    <input name="_timezone" id="_timezone" value="_default_" type="hidden" />
        <input name="ajax" id="ajax" value="1" type="hidden" />

    User <input name="_user" id="_user" type="text"  value="anupam@excoflare.com"/><br>
    Pass <input name="_pass" id="_pass"type="password"  value="anupam123"/><br>

    <input type="submit" >

</form>
```

it will work correctly.But i want to auto login roundcubemail via java script with window.open method for my p

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you want do do a POST request instead of a GET request. This might help you:
[JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)